# Facebook: Authorize user on server after successful login on JS

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using sdk that facebook provides(in java-script), to add login option in my site with facebook. I succeed to do this on client side, but I want to identify this user on server side without php-sdk.

So I need from client side send a request to server, that will prove that (for example) user with ID 1234 in Facebook, indeed logged in to my site. I don't want to use php-sdk, because it's the only time I will use it, so it's seems to me a waste to load all the sdk just for that.

Comment: why would it be a waste? You load it in your login verification script, and don't load it elsewhere. That's like saying it's a waste of have an oven in your kitchen because you only use it at suppertime while cooking.

Comment: So its a common thing, to use js and php sdk just for login?